# Check if SQLServer table is empty

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

In my WPF-application, I want to start a window only to be shown, if there a no data in the table "Betrieb". 
So, I know that I can check this with "select count from Betrieb". My problem is, how to get the count into my application.

```
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

is wrong and does not work.

Does anybody have advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Object i = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

This method returns an object value with the count and you can cast the object type you want.

Answer (score 1):

By the way if your query is like this you must get an error. Change your query like this:

`select count(**Column_Name**) from Betrieb`